# How to parse this SVG and manipulate using SnapSVG?

Tags: html

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1399.99 980.24">
  <title>
    
    nature
  
  </title>
  <g id="clouds">
    <path d="M295.68 309.65l-1 0a51.46 51.46 0 0 0-99.81-4.73c-0.7 0-1.41-0.07-2.12-0.07a34 34 0 1 0 24 58.21 51.46 51.46 0 0 0 58.95-2.8 29.26 29.26 0 1 0 20-50.64Z" transform="translate(-0.01)" fill="#123"/>
    <path d="M1207.87 325.34a25.29 25.29 0 0 0-9.05 1.67 35.58 35.58 0 0 0-33.63-11.11 45.74 45.74 0 1 0-14.13 63.24 35.52 35.52 0 0 0 47.76-4.75 25.36 25.36 0 1 0 9.05-49Z" transform="translate(-0.01)" fill="#123"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want to parse this SVG and change the color of that.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. The code appears to be OK. The color #123 ist rather black, may this is confusing you? Try other values, like #1a1, #a11 or so.